# Converting to text file after XSL transformation

Tags: file, xslt, text, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I managed to perform the XSLT transformation in an input XML file and generate the transformed output XML file. Now, the requirement I am getting is that the output file should be a text file instead of a XML file. Is there any standard functionality to generate the transformed text file instead of XML file in AX 2012?

Comment: You can use XSLT to output a "text" file.  However, the term "text file" is extremely general and does not describe anything specific.  It could be as simple as renaming the output from `.xml` to `.txt`, or much more complex, such as producing some custom format.  Unless you can provide more details on what you mean by "text file", this question is unanswerable in its present state.

Comment: By text file, I meant to say .txt file. I visual studio in the xslt file if I use value "text" in the output method, it generates the .txt file but I do not know how to do that in AX 2012. I used value "text" in the xslt in ax 2012 as well but it is just generating XML file instead of .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You must separate two concepts here:

1. The *name* of the output, which includes an extension after the dot, which *can*  indicate the type of file; and
2. the *content* and *format* of the output file.

These are technically independent.  I think you've established that you want the output named `something.txt`.  However, you haven't specified what the file's content and format need to be.

The content and format are determined by the specifications (tags) in your XSL stylesheet.  The XSL specifies rules for reading some XML format and transforming it to something else.  The XSL can be written to output XML or any other format you desire.  Although the *input* to a stylesheet transform must be XML, there are very few limitations on what can be written.  (In XSLT2 and later, you can even read non-XML input, but I don't think that's of interest here)

If your stylesheet outputs XML, the content and format will be XML regardless of the filename and extension.  If all you need is to output whatever the stylesheet produces currently, but have it named `something.txt`, then you need to look at how the XSL transformer is invoked, and specify the correct output filename.

If you need some other format, then the stylesheet will need to be rewritten to output that format, and that task is beyond what can be explained here.